# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component in react 18

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, navbar, react-dom

I am new in react facing some issues in hooks can't able to resolve the problem. Can anybody help me.

react.development.js:207 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem

`App.js`

```
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./components/Pages/Home";
import { About } from "./components/Pages/About";
import { Blog } from "./components/Pages/Blog";
import { Contact } from "./components/Pages/Contact";


function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <NavBar />

        <div className="pages">
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
            <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog/>} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

`ERROR`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjzCW.png)

`Navbar.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./NavBar.css";

NavBar()

export default function NavBar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="nav-container">
          <NavLink exact to="/" className="nav-logo">
            CodeBucks
            <i className="fas fa-code"></i>
          </NavLink>

          <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                exact
                to="/"
                activeClassName="active"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                Home
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                exact
                to="/about"
                activeClassName="active"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                About
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                exact
                to="/blog"
                activeClassName="active"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                Blog
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                exact
                to="/contact"
                activeClassName="active"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                Contact Us
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div className="nav-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={click ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"}></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

if i remove navbar() from navbar.js more errors are showing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSim.png)

package.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNx33.png)

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

Comment: I don't think you should call NavBar(). A NavBar element is created automatically when you use <NavBar />. Also please post your index.tsx, the useRef error seems to come from index.tsx

Comment: ok edited index.js

Comment: The error comes from index.tsx not index.js

Answer (score 2):

You called `NavBar()` inside your file.

```
NavBar()

export default function NavBar() {
```

Comment: because its is react.js 18 that's why

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the component like the general function in the Navbar.js.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./NavBar.css";
[enter image description here][1]
// Please remove this line
// NavBar()

export default function NavBar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="nav-container">
          <NavLink exact to="/" className="nav-logo">
            CodeBucks
            <i className="fas fa-code"></i>
          </NavLink>

          <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                exact
                to="/"
                activeClassName="active"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                Home
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                exact
                to="/about"
                activeClassName="active"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                About
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                exact
                to="/blog"
                activeClassName="active"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                Blog
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                exact
                to="/contact"
                activeClassName="active"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                Contact Us
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div className="nav-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={click ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"}></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

React Component should not be called like a function. That should settled inside of DOM element.

Comment: if i remove that line more errors are showing

Comment: Please show me the error

Comment: Can you show me your package.json file

Comment: edited package.json

Comment: From the package.json, I can't find the `react-router-dom` module. Please check `package.json` file again, and check if you have already installed `react-router-dom`.